# How to debug a recursive function to a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function using Python 3.8.5 to extract all the keys in a nested dictionary. The nested dictionary can go into unknown depths, and might include lists, strings and integers as values. The lists might contain other lists or dictionaries, or some blob at some point.

So far, I have come up with something like this:

```
def scanNested(data):
    store = []
    for k,v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            store.append(k)
            scanNested(v)
        elif isinstance(v,list):
            for d in list:
                if isinstance(d,dict):
                    scanNested(d)
        else:
            store.append(k)
    return store
```

My nested dictionaries will be similar to the format below:

```
data = {'1': {'foo': 'bar',
  'a': '2',
  'b': '0',
  'c': '3',
  'd': '',
  'e': [{'dur': 'fur', 'g': '6', '7': {'t': 'zeri', 'z': 'feri'}},
   {'ham': 'doo', 'tam': 'zuu', 'too': {'koo': 'boo', 'noo': 'moo'}}]}}
```

When I apply the function to this dictionary as posted above, I only receive the key from the first dictionary, `["1"]` in this case, but not the other ones deep in the nest.

I can't figure out why this happens, and how can I fix this issue.

I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

**EDIT:** The initial question was throwing a type error since the iteration, as shown above, mistakenly was trying to iterate over a built-in object type, list. As pointed out by Klaus, it should have iterate through the `"v"` which is an instance of the built-in list object.

Comment: `for d in list:` → `for d in v:`?

Comment: Thank you so so much, I looked at it maybe hundred times and couldn't see it. It works now.

Comment: @Edfern When I tried your function with `for d in list:` replaced with `for d in v:`, I get the output `['1']` with the dictionary you gave.

Comment: Don't edit the original error out! The question will not be helpful for others anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how:

```
def scanNested(data, store):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            store.append(k)
            scanNested(v, store)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            scanNested(v, store)
    return store

data = {'1': {'foo': 'bar',
  'a': '2',
  'b': '0',
  'c': '3',
  'd': '',
  'e': [{'dur': 'fur', 'g': '6', '7': {'t': 'zeri', 'z': 'feri'}},
   {'ham': 'doo', 'tam': 'zuu', 'too': {'koo': 'boo', 'noo': 'moo'}}]}}

print(scanNested(data, []))
```

Output:

```
['1', 'foo', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'dur', 'g', '7', 't', 'z', 'ham', 'tam', 'too', 'koo', 'noo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Being inspired from Ann Zen's great answer, if one might need to keep the function with single argument, this worked for me as well:

```
def scanNested(data):
    store = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        store.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            store.extend(scanNested(v))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                if isinstance(d, dict):
                    store.extend(scanNested(d))
    return store
```